# How can I add new contracts generated from a factory to my drizzle-react app?

Tags: truffle, react, drizzle

I have a Factory contract which creates new contracts. How do I get the new contract into my drizzle-react web app?

I am using  to send the transaction to create a new contract but I don't know how to get the data it returns...

Answer (score 0):

In summary, the factory makes the deployed contract addresses discoverable. This is by emitting an event with created address and/or storing them in an array with functions to explore the state - preferably both.

The app then uses the ABI for the deployed contract(s) at the addresses where the factory informs it something exists.

Hope it helps.